# ImageMagick convert from TikZ figure produces weird result

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, tikz

### Problem

I am getting two different results when using TikZ and standalone to convert to png.
The same happens when I directly use ImageMagick 6.8 `convert from.pdf to.png` as well.

Why does this happen...?

#### Expected result

The output should look like

[image]

#### Actual result

The result of running either `lualatex`  or `convert tikzmwe.pdf tikzmwe.png` is the same and results in the following png.

[image]

`convert` also give me this message:

`convert: profile 'icc': 'RGB ': RGB color space not permitted on grayscale PNG 'tikzmwe.png' @ warning/png.c/MagickPNGWarningHandler/1748.`

### Minimum working example

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=0pt, convert={outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\sharedkey}{%
    \raisebox{-.5 ex}{\tikz{%
    \draw[fill=blue, draw=white] (0ex,0) arc(90:270:1ex) -- cycle;
    \draw[fill=red, draw=white] (0ex,0) arc(90:-90:1ex) -- cycle; }}}
\begin{document}
\(x = \sharedkey\)
\end{document}
```

Compile with `lualatex -shell-escape tikzmwe.tex`.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the ImageMagick version you used into your question?

Comment: Also, the question structure confused me a little bit at first. You refer to a Makefile that isn't there. I think one could slim the question down a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an ImageMagick bug to me. I checked on two versions and got different results:

Cannot reproduce:

- Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2019-11-12

Can reproduce:

- Version: ImageMagick 6.9.11-24 Q16 x86_64 20200718

  (not seeing the warning, though)

The halving of the circle is excess white from the `draw=white`: when using another stroke color, the lower circle half is entirely filled with that color.

I wasn't able to check on the current ImageMagick 7. Filing a bug is only an option if the bug can be reproduced on the current stable version.

Comment: Updated to ImageMagick 7.0.10-34 with good results. Thanks!